# DirectInput PS3 Controller

Tags: controller, directinput, playstation3

I am working with DirectInput to access Gamepads/Joysticks as Input Devices for several applications. Most of the Joysticks are recognized and the sent data can be accessed by DirectInput, except when I'm using my PS3 Controlelr (no, the controller is not broken, since I have two and tested both). The PS3 Controller is recognized as joystick but there is no data transferring with DirectInput. Does anybody know if there is something else required when using a PS3 Controller?

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the top hits on Google for this problem, so:

- open the "Devices and Printers" control panel in windows, select the controller, open the test panel. If you see your controller input there it is most likely a code problem.
- if you see no input there please install "Playstation Now on PC" from the official Playstation website. During installation it should prompt for a device driver installation for controllers.

I just did that, and the PS3 controller starts to work. It even shows a few more axes than before.